# Need to toggle items between lists using Master/Detail paradigm (Angular)

Tags: angular, typescript, master-detail

I would like to toggle items between 2 lists based on a boolean property.  I am having trouble understanding how to get the list component to re-render and display the updated list.

When the "Change Shift" button is pressed, the "nocturnal" property toggles and the class changes. The behavior that is missing is that I also want the item (i.e., Batman) to move from the Night list to the Day list

My app component includes the master (list) and detail components.  Template code:

```
<div>
  <my-list [list]="listSource"></my-list>
  <my-detail [selected]="selectedItem"></my-detail>
</div>
```

List component template:

```
<div class="column list">
  <h2>List</h2>
  <h3>Day Shift</h3>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of listDay" class="{{ item.nocturnal ? 'night':'day'}}">{{ item.name }}</li>
  </ul>
  <h3>Night Shift</h3>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of listNight" class="{{ item.nocturnal ? 'night':'day'}}">{{ item.name }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The master list is filtered in the List component into `listDay` and `listNight` like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.listNight = this.list.filter(item => item.nocturnal);
  this.listDay = this.list.filter(item => !item.nocturnal);
}
```

Detail component template:

```
<div class="column detail">
  <h2>Detail</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>name: {{selected.name}}</li>
    <li>job: {{selected.job}}</li>
    <li>shift: {{selected.nocturnal ? 'Night':'Day'}}</li>
    <li><button (click)="toggleShift()">Change Shift</button></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here's a basic Plunkr illustrating the issue:
http://plnkr.co/edit/yJLtROrmfKjEYqj5yJ1N?p=preview

Comment: Could you please specify what exactly you mean by toggle items and display updated list?

Comment: do you want the lists to change color? or only the night/day lists be displayed one at a time

Comment: When the "Change Shift" button is pressed, the "nocturnal" property toggles and the class changes.  The behavior that is missing is that I also want the item (i.e., Batman) to move from the Night list to the Day list.

Comment: oh, okay. let me see if I can update my answer to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if FussinHussin's existing answer gives you what you described as your problem. I was able to successfully shift "Batman" back and forth from Day and Night list when the toggle button was pressed. Here are the updated plunker files I modified.

*app.ts*

```
// root app component
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

import {List} from './list.component'
import {Detail} from './detail.component'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <my-list [list]="listSource"></my-list>
      <my-detail [selected]="selectedItem" (shiftChange)="shiftChanged($event)"></my-detail>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  listSource:any
  selectedItem:any;
  constructor() {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`;
    this.listSource = [{
      'name':'Batman',
      'job':'Detective',
      'nocturnal':true
    },{
      'name':'Superman',
      'job':'Carpenter',
      'nocturnal':false
    },{
      'name':'Aquaman',
      'job':'Plumber',
      'nocturnal':false
    },{
      'name':'Herman',
      'job':'Physicist',
      'nocturnal':true
    }];
    this.selectedItem = this.listSource[0];
  }
shiftChanged(listItem: any) {
  let index = null;
  for (let i=0; i<this.listSource.length; i++) {
    if (listItem.name === this.listSource[i].name) {
      index = i;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (index !== null) {
    this.listSource[index].nocturnal = listItem.nocturnal;
    this.listSource = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.listSource));
  }
}
}
// root module
@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App, List, Detail ],
  providers:[  ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

*detail.component.ts*

```
// detail component
import {Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-detail',
  template: `
    <div class="column detail">
      <h2>Detail</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>name: {{selected.name}}</li>
        <li>job: {{selected.job}}</li>
        <li>shift: {{selected.nocturnal ? 'Night':'Day'}}</li>
        <li><button (click)="toggleShift()">Change Shift</button></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class Detail {
  @Input() selected: any;
  @Output() shiftChange = new EventEmitter<any>();
  toggleShift() {
    this.selected.nocturnal = !this.selected.nocturnal;
    this.shiftChange.emit(this.selected);
  }
}
```

*list.component.ts*

```
// list component
import {Component, Input, OnInit, OnChanges, SimpleChange} from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-list',
  template: `
    <div class="column list">
      <h2>List</h2>
      <h3>Day Shift</h3>
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let item of listDay" class="{{ item.nocturnal ? 'night':'day'}}">{{ item.name }}</li>
      </ul>
      <h3>Night Shift</h3>
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let item of listNight" class="{{ item.nocturnal ? 'night':'day'}}">{{ item.name }}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  `,
})

export class List implements OnInt, OnChanges{
  @Input() list: any;
  listNight:any;
  listDay:any;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.listNight = this.list.filter(item => item.nocturnal);
    this.listDay = this.list.filter(item => !item.nocturnal);
  }

  ngOnChanges(change: SimpleChange) {
    for (let prop in change) {
      if (prop === 'list') {
        let list = change[prop];
         this.listNight = list.currentValue.filter(item => item.nocturnal);
         this.listDay = list.currentValue.filter(item => !item.nocturnal);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You could modify the files even further to optimize. But this will give you a head start as I was only focusing on getting the functionality working for your plunker. (confirmed this to work locally in plunker). Hope it helps.

Comment: I was trying to update my answer if you would have just given me a minute :P

Comment: I'm sorry FussinHussin, I had already taken an interest in the problem if you look at the comments under the OP. Then while working on the plunker saw your answer which still wasn't quite what the OP intended. So I just thought of finishing it on the plunker. It happens sometimes, hope you understand :)

Answer (score 1):

Alright, your plunker was a bit messy, so I started from scratch. instead of two child components to one parent, I just did one child to one parent. but this method you can still implement with a couple of changes.

you could solve this with ngOnChanges, observables, or mutable data(this solution uses mutable data). in the future, I would recommend getting this data from a server, and using a behavior subject to track updates, as it bogs your application down much less than ngOnChanges, and observables are a good practice.

the reason your method wasn't working is Angular's change detection wasn't working, because the list was mutated. That's how I got around it, every time a change was made, I used the spread (`...`) operator to copy the contents of the original list and created a new list. here ya go.

here is a [stackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/persist-list-to-child?file=app/app.component.ts) of the answer, you can use this to build your version.

if you want to learn more about the smart/dumb master/detail pattern, you can look [here](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-smart-components-vs-presentation-components-whats-the-difference-when-to-use-each-and-why/)